# Left Join with Multiple Criteria

Tags: r, merge

I have two datas and I'd like to do a left join with 2 criteria.

> Criteria 1 : Same Title
>
> Criteria 2 : Date between StartDate & EndDate

**Data B**

```
Title  Date
A      2018-07-01
B      2019-12-30
```

**Data A**

```
Title StartDate  EndDate     Score
A     2018-01-01 2018-05-18    0
A     2018-05-19 2019-01-01    1
B     2019-10-01 2020-02-01    4
B     2020-02-02 2020-10-01    7
```

This is what I want to get

```
Title  Score
A       1
B       4
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a non-equi join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DataA)[DataB,  .(Title, Score), on = 
      .(Title, StartDate < Date, EndDate >= Date)]
#   Title Score
#1:     A     1
#2:     B     4
```

#### data

```
DataA <- structure(list(Title = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
StartDate = structure(c(17532, 
17670, 18170, 18294), class = "Date"), EndDate = structure(c(17669, 
17897, 18293, 18536), class = "Date"), Score = c(0L, 1L, 4L, 
7L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

DataB <- structure(list(Title = c("A", "B"), Date = structure(c(17713, 
18260), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more edit. How should I edit if I want to keep DataB in my new Data set?

Comment: @SeqenenreTao you can do `setDT(DataA)[DataB,  .(Title, Score, Date = StartDate), on = 
      .(Title, StartDate < Date, EndDate >= Date)]`

Comment: I had some problem with that solution. In your formula you used: "StartDate < Date, EndDate >= Date)". When "Date" == "StartDate" I got NA. On the other hand we can not use "StartDate <= Date, EndDate >= Date" in order to not dublicate. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @SeqenenreTao if it is equality, just use `Date = StartDate`  You can use `StartDate <= Date, EndDate >= Date` depends on the condition